# How to create a pseudo-column showing the "occurrence number" in a day in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

NOTE: PostgreSQL 9.4

Let's say I have a table like this:

- column `project_name`: text, not null;
- column `date`: timestamp without time zone, not null;
- column `uuid`: UUID, not null;
- unique index on all three columns.

Let's say that for a given `project_name`, there are several `date` occurrences in the same day. For instance:

```
    uuid     | project_name |    analysis_date
-------------|------------------------------------
 uuid-1-here |  MY_PROJECT  | 2016-02-22 10:00:00
 uuid-2-here |  MY_PROJECT  | 2016-02-22 10:20:00
 uuid-3-here |  MY_PROJECT  | 2016-02-24 13:12:00
```

And this pattern can repeat: I can have several analyses on, say Feb 23, Jan 12th, Dec 30th 2015, etc etc.

I'd like to obtain an output like this:

```
    uuid     | project_name | analysis_day | occurrence
-------------|------------------------------------------
 uuid-1-here |  MY_PROJECT  |  2016-02-22  |     1
 uuid-2-here |  MY_PROJECT  |  2016-02-22  |     2
 uuid-3-here |  MY_PROJECT  |  2016-02-24  |     1
```

That is, *for each day*, have the pseudo column `occurrence` show the analysis number which occurred that day -- for each day.

OK, so, formatting for `analysis_day` I can manage; but I don't have the slightest idea of how to generate that `occurrence` column :(

My first readings tell me that I should use some sort of `PARTITION` but that is a part of SQL which completely eludes me, and that doesn't help. Maybe a partition is not even the solution here.

How can I achieve the above?

Comment: use analytic functions such as `Select uuid, project_name, analysis_day, row_number() over (partition by project_name, analysis_date order by uuid) as occurance from tableName`  window functions.  pretty cool and powerful stuff!

Comment: Try `row_number() over (partition by project_name, analysis_day ORDER BY uuid ) As occurence`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  uuid, project_name, to_char(analysis_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') d, count(*)
FROM    t
GROUP BY uuid, project_name, d
ORDER BY uuid, project_name, d
;
```

**EDIT**:

Okay, I realized you are not asking for a count but for the sequence number. In that case you can say this:

```
SELECT  uuid, project_name, to_char(analysis_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') d, 
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY analysis_date::date ORDER BY analysis_date)
FROM    t
ORDER BY uuid, project_name, d
;
```

Or if you want independent numbering within each project, include that in the `PARTITION` like this: `PARTITION BY project_name, to_char(analysis_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')`.

Note that you are going to encounter time zone issues here, because Postgres has to decide when each day starts and ends. Since you have a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, there will be no automatic conversion based on the client's timezone settings.

Comment: the "timestamp without time zone" was what the client asked for, I advised against it but that's the client's choice :p

Comment: Well in Postgres a `timestamp with time zone` *does not actually store the time zone*! It only tells Postgres to format/parse strings with the client's timezone, and to use it when deciding what day an instant belongs to.

Comment: Yeah, well, too late now :/ But I didn't know that... Useful precision, thank you!

Comment: IMO `analysis_date::date` and `(partition by analysis_date::date order by analysis_date)` will be better...

Comment: @Abelisto I agree actually, but the question mentions formatting the date. You could still use the cast in the `PARTITION BY` though.

Comment: @Abelisto sorry, my postgresql-fu is poor; what is that `analysis_date::date` syntax?

Comment: Actually `::date` just cosmetics. My suggestion was more about `order by analysis_date` because you does not provide any order for `row_number()` function.

Comment: @fge In PostgreSQL `<value>::<type>` is alias for `cast(<value> as <type>)`, just shorter.

Comment: @Abelisto ordering the window function seems nice to keep it consistent between runs. I added that and switched to using casts.

Comment: :)) Not `order by analysis_date::date` but `order by analysis_date`. You should to provide the order inside partition.